# IntelliJ IDEA: How do I disable / ignore specific auto import suggestions?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, ide

For context, I'm writing a Node-TypeScript project and using IntellIJ Ultimate 2018.1.5

All was well until I started using the Node AWS SDK. Now, every time I specify a `Function` type, IDEA keeps pestering me to import it from `aws-sdk/clients/greengrass`.

[image]

How do I tell IntelliJ that I just want ordinary, inbuilt, `Functions`, not "Greengrass" functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such prompts may appear if you have a file in your source code/project dependencies that exports a module with a name matching built-in object name. For example, `node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/greengrass.d.ts` exports interface `Function`, so IDEA suggests importing it. For such names conflicts, excluding one of these conflicting libraries from indexing is the only way to go for now.
For example, you can try marking the corresponding `.d.ts/.js` file as plain text (*Mark as plain text* in file right-click menu)

We have a feature request to always prefer built-in types in such cases, [WEB-34452](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34452), please feel free to vote for it